# Adding to user dictionary in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm looking to make an app that adds a bunch of words to the users dictionary.

I know I can use UserDictionary.Words.AddWords however it is not actually adding the words to the dictionary.

It looks like "WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" permission was removed in M, is there a different way to add words to a users dictionary or is that completely gone now?

Comment: I think permission is not removed , please add your code

Comment: It is missing infact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UserDictionary.Words can no longer be accessed from Marshmallow (API 23) onwards.

Reference : [Android Issue Tracker - Issue 199199](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199199&can=4&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

> The user dictionary is now accessible only by the current spellchecker and keyboard. It was heavily abused by apps to scoop user dictionary. Out of the ten top apps using it there wasn't a single legit one. My favorite was the one which used a bug in keyguard to unlock the device after [it] "scans" [your] fingerprint from the screen! This is intended behavior.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. Anyway thanks for clearing up, was searching for it and I was unable to get any clue that where the heck it was gone. That bug looks terrible, is it possible to exploit this bug in pre-M devices still?